# What is a suitable fraction of process virtual memory size as the resident memory size

Tags: java, performance, memory

We are using 1 GB as the Java memory (`-Xmx`) size for our application. But it is running slow since it was processing high number of messages. The memory  usage is this:

```
PID     USER        PR  NI  VIRT         RES    SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+    COMMAND                                                                                         
34536 javarunner    20   0  5724m        970m  13m  S  6.3  0.3   22:48.69   java
```

That is, the virtual memory is 5724m and the resident set size is 970m.

Is this considered OK, to have such memory utilization where virtual memory is 5 times the resident set size?
Is there any formula or guidelines for ratio we should maintain for this ratio?

Comment: Why negative points are given for genuine question without explaining the reason. I am not asking someone to do my homework here. Just asked for any guideline available or good practices on this .

Comment: some more info would be nice. How much physical memory do you actually have? Do you have a gc log? What collector have you chosen or are running the default one? What JDK version are you running?
Generally speaking, running gc on heap that has been paged out to vm gives horrible performance.

Comment: Erik...  The answer should be independent of what programming language i am using. As this can be a generic question of what ratio of virtual and Residual memory we should maintain in say windows, linux machine.

Comment: zimmer Why should it be? Different languages and runtimes have different behaviours and react differently to, for instance, swapped out memory. The JVM gc process reacts badly to a swapped out heap. Looking at your post I would surmise that you receive a large number of messages and that gc is the culprit for your performance problems.

Comment: Erik .. we have 300 gb in ram. but i am not going to allocate 5gb to one process, which might see a spike once in a while. 1gb is in general good for it. 
I have check further my issue, even on restarting the process with 1gb of  -Xmx  the OS ( redhat) is allocating 5724 mb of virtual memory. So the slowness is not due to virtual memory.  Further later  i found our DB (sybase ASE, 15.7) is running slow intermittently, which has caused the issue.
 But i asked for guideline on virtual to REs memory , which i have got  below. So thanks for your time and concern. Appreciated.

Comment: zimmer Without a gc log you don't know that nor do you seem to know anything about what the java process is doing at all. But it's your funeral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here i am answering based on some research via google and have found mentioning of this in various article.

"Microsoft recommends that you set virtual memory to be no less than 1.5 times and no more than 3 times the amount of RAM on your computer."

Have not found any direct mentioning of this by Microsoft official documentation. but Google result were flooded with this answer. I believe this ratio should also hold good in linux/unix os case.
Also this ratio should be is generic, as expected, independent of what programming language is used by the application.